# Notifications in openstack

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I'm interested how to notify other applications of events in openstack. For example I want't to know in my application when an instance in nova was suspended or resumed. Are there any webhooks or something like that where could I get that info?

I was looking at official documentation on notification but I can't really make anything out of that:
http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/openstack-network/admin/content/ch_adv_notification_overview.html

I could not find any examples with code on the web too.

Has anyone been doing anything like this yet?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the OpenStack [Ceilometer](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/ceilometer/) project. It captures different kinds of OpenStack events and log them into a database. The primary use case is for metering, but you may find it useful for your situation.

Comment: See also [Alarms](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/ceilometer/webapi/v2.html#alarms)