# Notifications to external systems from openstack

Tags: java, notifications, openstack, openstack-nova

We want to develop an application which will monitor the host(s) and VM(s), managed via openstack. We use the openstack REST APIs to get the inventory of hosts and servers. Next step is to listen for any notifications/events from openstack environment such as Vm down, VM suspended,etc. We don't want to rely on the ceilometer, since this may not be a mandatory component in our deployments.

One way is latching into rabbitmq messaging from nova. If this is the ideal way, is there any Java client already written to use this mechanism? The problem with this approach is that I need to know the username and password for rabbitmq, which may be different than that of openstack controller credentials.

So we are checking whats the best way to get the notifications (specifically the compute events such as VM down, VM suspended,etc)  from openstack environment to an external application, without using cielometer.

I have come across another post "[Notifications in openstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325328/notifications-in-openstack)" which was talking about a similar issue. But the answer provided was using cielometer, which I don't want to go with.

Comment: why not just used something zabbix